# ssh config, how to get many 'Host' entries to do the same thing?

Tags: ssh

I have an .ssh/config file that gives several names for the same remote host, e.g.:-

```
Host cheddar
HostName cheddar.halon.org.uk
Host halon
HostName cheddar.halon.org.uk
```

Then I have an entry for    cheddar.halon.org.uk which specifies various things for that host.  I was expecting that the configuration at the            cheddar.halon.org.uk would get executed when I used 'cheddar' or 'halon' for the ssh connection but it doesn't.  The cheddar.halon.org.uk configuration only gets set when I do 'ssh cheddar.halon.org.uk'.

Is there any way to get the same configuration when using a number of different names for a host?

Comment: At least with OpenSSH, the `Host` key accepts a whitespace separated list (or even a pattern). So you can use a single `Host cheddar halon` line followed by common settings. Maybe that would help?

Comment: Yes, youi're absolutely right, that's the way to do it.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, that's the way to do it.

I now have:-

`Host cheddar.halon.org.uk cheddar halon
    PermitLocalCommand yes
    # LocalCommand echo "Local command runs" >/tmp/lc
    LocalCommand rsync --update -a -e "ssh -o PermitLocalCommand=no" ~/.cfg/ halon:.cfg/ &
    Hostname cheddar.halon.org.uk`

Comment: ... and I can't get the hang of using markdown to indicate code! :-)

Comment: Markdown is limited in comments - you might want to consider posting your successful config as a self-answer instead

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's the answer to my specific requirement. As noted above in the comments, one can put more than one name in the `Host` line:

```
Host cheddar.halon.org.uk cheddar halon
    Hostname cheddar.halon.org.uk
```

Very simple!